# Black desktop background

Tags: greeter, wallpaper

After changing my desktop background using a custom image, my desktop stays black, while the login screen has been reverted to the default image. How can I fix that (without copying the image to /usr/share/backgrounds)?

Comment: Will you please try my answer and let me know :)

Comment: @Ravan: Somehow it works now without changing, but in the background selection screen I can find a black image...

Comment: Ah? I still get black background for custom section (which you have asked) :)

Comment: can you please tell me "somehow"? I can't do that without following the below answers.

Comment: Will you please drop [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32781/ravan-and-arc-lupus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell/+bug/1524723 did not appear in *0.3.2*.

The solution would be update to *0.3.2*

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue in 0.3.2.

Comment: Will you please open a new post, for me and OP it was solved in 0.3.2 :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `dconf`

Install dconf with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open `dconf` org --> gnome --> desktop --> background.

Change picture uri. (total path of image)

[image: Imgur]

If not working:

Open terminal and run:

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.background
```

Now try again to change the background.

The command form to change background is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/thepathtoyourfile/yourNewBackgroundFile.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gnome-tweak-tool` to change background:

Install from software center,then open it. You can change background under Desktop tab

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wallch`. Install it from software center.

Wallch is a General purpose Wallpaper Changer.

You can shuffle background after a predefined time interval. Browse to the location, import. Now right click on it for options.

[image: Imgur]