# Wallpaper bigger that screen breaks wallpaper

Tags: wallpaper

So I downloaded the following wallpaper and put it in my pictures folder. I go into settings and click on the thumbnail. My desktop changes to a black background and that is it. Any idea what is wrong?

http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/49/38/SQEcnG.jpg

Comment: It may be related to http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3435/black-desktop-background . Trying this out and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

instead of selecting from System Settings, go to your pictures folder,right click and select 'set as desktop background'that should work nicely